# Как подключать CSS-стили в Shopify?

Tags: css, cms, интернет-магазин

Как подключать CSS-стили в Shopify?

Я знаю как подключать стили CSS , когда они лежат все в папке assets , но  хочу их сложить в assets/css/Css-стили , чтобы не было грязи. И возможно ли это?Потому , что я хотел найти сам перерыл и рунет и английский ничего годного не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Просто продолжите путь по новым папкам.
Если у Вас раньше было /assets/style.css , то станет /assets/css/style.css
Надеюсь я Вас правильно понял.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the ActionBar in an Android app, you can use the getSupportActionBar() method to get a reference to the ActionBar object and then call various methods on it to change its properties. For example:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

You can also customize the layout of the ActionBar by creating a custom layout file and setting it as the ActionBar's custom view. To do this, you can use the setCustomView() method and pass it the layout resource ID:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Finally, you can also customize the appearance of the ActionBar by using a custom theme that modifies the ActionBar's style. For example, you can use the windowActionBar property in your theme to change the color and appearance of the ActionBar.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

You can then apply this theme to your app by setting it in the android:theme attribute in the  element of your app's manifest file.

You can also built your Shopify mobile application as it is the current needs of the businesses. To help you out for building Shopify mobile app you may visit https://appokart.com/ , here you will get the proper guidance to use every Shopify tool.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык. 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)